# Laravel 8 route order from bottom to top

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I have installed Laravel 8 and work perfectly, and then i tried to learn about routing and try to make some routes like this

```
Route::view('testing', 'welcome')->name('testingWelcome');
Route::get('testing',[TestingController::class, 'noParameter'])->name('testingNoParam');
Route::view('testing', 'dashboard')->name('testingDashboard');
```

Some post in here said that routes in web.php work from top to bottom. But, thats not what i get when i called in url http://localhost/laraps/public/testing. it always called the bottom one. i tried to change the order, but still the last one always get called.

Any explanation for this one? or am i made any wrong configuration?

thanks for any help

Comment: Which route gets called if you comment out the last one?

Comment: with that order, commenting the last one will gonna get the second route, the one to the TestingController

Comment: The post was probably referring to routes with potentially conflicting names e.g. `testing/{parameter}` and `testing/{differentlyNamedParameter}` because they would get register as different routes and the first one will be resolved when calling `testing/valueForParameter` when the name is identical the route will overwrite the previous routes of the same name and method

Comment: @apokryfos, so it means because both 3 of them have the same name "testing", so the last will override the previous routes?

Comment: Yes, you can confirm this by doing `php artisan route:list` . Only one of the three would be listed (I would expect). You can experiment with `Route::view('testing/{optional?}', 'welcome');` as one the first route to verify this as well.

Comment: Yes you are right. there are only 1 "testing" listed in after i run php artisan route:list. Laravel override it, i thought there are should be an error if more than 1 same route, but its not. Thanks for your help @apokryfos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A short explanation for this would be that each call to `Route::{verb}` creates a new route entry under your route collection ([relevant code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php#L60)). `{verb}` ban be any HTTP verb e.g. `get`, or `post` etc.  This entry is created under an array entry `[{verb}][domain/url]`.

This means that when a new route is registered that matches the same URL with the same method it will overwrite the old one.

So in the case

```
Route::view('testing', 'welcome')->name('testingWelcome');
Route::get('testing',[TestingController::class, 'noParameter'])->name('testingNoParam');
Route::view('testing', 'dashboard')->name('testingDashboard');
```

Only the 3rd declaration actually "sticks". There are cases where multiple route definitions can match the same URL for example assume you have these routes:

```
Route::view('testing', 'welcome')->name('testingWelcome');
Route::get('testing/{optionalParameter?}',[TestingController::class, 'parameter'])->name('testingNoParam');
Route::view('testing/{otherParameter?}', 'dashboard')->name('testingDashboard');
```

In this case all 3 routes are added to the route collection, however when accessing URL `example.com/testing` the **first** matched route will be the one that will be called in this case the `welcome` view. This is because since all 3 routes are declared, once the router finds one matching route, it stops looking for more matches.

Note: There's generally no point in declaring multiple routes with the exact same URL so this is mainly an academic exercise. However there is often a use case for cases like e.g. `model/{id}` and model/list` to differentiate between getting info for a specific model and getting a list of models. In this case it's important to declare the routes as:

```
Route::get('model/list',  [ ModelController::class, 'list' ]);
Route::get('model/{id}',  [ ModelController::class, 'view' ]);
```

However you can be more explicit in route declarations using:

```
Route::get('model/{id}',  [ ModelController::class, 'view' ])->where('id', 
'\d+');
Route::get('model/list',  [ ModelController::class, 'list' ]);
```

in this case the order does not matter because Laravel knows `id` can only be a number and therefore will not match `model/list`

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation @apokryfos. 
Im adding more parameters and another keyword like on your explanation above. And realizing it seems looks like a Polymorphism Overloading in Java.